# Wordpress - How to get rid of duplicates of the same file? (GTmetrix test report)

Tags: wordpress, performance, gtmetrix

The report of a GTmetrix test for my wordpress website (home page) reveals that there are duplicates of certain files Here's the link to the `[GTmetrix test report][2]`.  [image: Also see the photo:]

It of course is not good for my website loading. I wanna know why that happens and how to fix it?**

Here's some info you might need: 
URL: www.anantamassage.com
Website: WordPress
My theme: ListingPro 
Website Builder: WP Bakery Page Builder
Optimization plugin: WP Rocket (Premium), Asset Clean up

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Those are all different font files that you're calling from google fonts. You need them all for different variations of the font - ie. bold / italic etc

Comment: But I just did a retest and the number of duplicates is now 2. In that case, why this happens? 
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/anantamassage.com/rmet0PtU

Comment: Probably the two youtube videos you have on the site, both calling the same fonts - remove them and see what happens.